# How to Trace a Real-Life Flower Using Polar Equations?

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, trace

Here is the flower I'm trying to trace:

$\hskip2cm$[image]

How can I trace this flower using polar equations? I currently have the formulas 
\begin{align}
r_{1}&=1.75\sin(10\,\theta + 18) +3\\
r_{2}&= 1.5\cos(10\,\theta+8)+3\\
r_{3}&=1.3
\end{align}

However, it fails to precisely match the outline of the flower. I am allowed to use any number of equations, as long as it matches the outline.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: "I am allowed"? Competition, exam? And you expect somebody will do your homework?

Comment: Any ideas of your own, possibly based on physical measurements from your photograph...?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, no it is a challenge in a fun program. Andrew D. Hwang, I am thinking of graphing individual ellipses to match each petal, and I am trying to figure out how to apply transformations.